# count trip in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

### my table structure

```
id zoneid status
1   35     IN   starting  zone 
2   35     OUT 1st trip has been started
3   36     IN
4   36     IN
5   36     OUT
6   38     IN last station zone 1 trip completed 
7   38     OUT returning back 2nd trip has start
8   38     OUT
9   36     IN
10  36     OUT
11  35     IN when return back in start zone means 2nd trip complete
12  35     IN
13  35     IN
14  35     OUT 3rd trip has been started 
15  36     IN
16  36     IN
17  36     OUT
18  38     IN 3rd trip has been completed
19  38     OUT 4th trip has been started
20  38     OUT
21  36     IN
22  36     OUT
23  35     IN 4th trip completed
24  35     IN
```

now i want a sql query, so i can count no of trips. i do not want to use status field for count
**edit**

i want result total trips
where 35 is the starting point and 38 is the ending point(this is 1 trip), when  again 35 occures after 38 means 2 trip and so on.

Comment: Can you tell us why you do not want to use status field for count?

Comment: @sk DO you mean you dont want to use the status field as logic in the count or you dont want it in the results?

Comment: Can you describe - in words - how we are supposed to know when  a trip starts?

Comment: @Matt i do not want to use status field for count. 1 trip means while zone id has 35 and 38 value.

Comment: @sk, from ur definition, a trip is when a *train* leaves from zone 35 and enters 38. From the outlook they are 2. But do you mean back n forth as your comments suggests (besides status column above)?

Comment: @Saad yes exactly, i want this.

Comment: are there any other columns in that table? in particular a datetime column for when a row is created?

Comment: @Used_By_Already yes there are many other columns id,datetime,lat,lng,deviceid am querying this data for one day only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't want to look at the status, but only look at the `zoneid` changes ordered by id. `zoneid` 36 is irrelevant, so we select 35 and 38 only, order them by id and count changes. We detect changes by comparing a record with the previous one. We can look into a previous record with LAG.

```
select sum(ischange) as trips_completed
from
(
  select 
    case when zoneid <> lag(zoneid) over (order by id) then 1 else 0 end as ischange
  from trips
  where zoneid in (35,38)
) changes_detected;
```

Comment: This solution does not takes care of all complete trips. If I just add one more row for zone=38 and status=OUT, it will give me 5 trips, whereas its an incomplete trip by the definition, trip is either (35/out and then 38/in) or (38/out and then 35/in). Unless the OP has a different definition of a trip

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting this without any testing. Does the following query produce the correct number of rows? Note if there is a date_created (datetime) column then I would suggest using that column to order by instead of id.

```
select
       ca.in_id, t.id as out_id, ca.in_status, t.status as out_status
from table1 t
cross apply (
   select top (1) id as in_id, status as in_status
   from table1
   where table1.id < t.id
   and zoneid = 35
   order by id DESC
   ) ca
where t.zoneid = 38
/* and conditions for selecting one day only */
```

If that logic is correct then just use COUNT(*) instead of the column list.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("id" int, "zoneid" int, "status" varchar(3), "other" varchar(54))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "zoneid", "status", "other")
VALUES
    (1, 35, 'IN', 'starting  zone'),
    (2, 35, 'OUT', '1st trip has been started'),
    (3, 36, 'IN', NULL),
    (4, 36, 'IN', NULL),
    (5, 36, 'OUT', NULL),
    (6, 38, 'IN', 'last station zone 1 trip completed'),
    (7, 38, 'OUT', 'returning back 2nd trip has start'),
    (8, 38, 'OUT', NULL),
    (9, 36, 'IN', NULL),
    (10, 36, 'OUT', NULL),
    (11, 35, 'IN', 'when return back in start zone means 2nd trip complete'),
    (12, 35, 'IN', NULL),
    (13, 35, 'IN', NULL),
    (14, 35, 'OUT', '3rd trip has been started'),
    (15, 36, 'IN', NULL),
    (16, 36, 'IN', NULL),
    (17, 36, 'OUT', 'other'),
    (18, 38, 'IN', '3rd trip has been completed'),
    (19, 38, 'OUT', '4th trip has been started'),
    (20, 38, 'OUT', NULL),
    (21, 36, 'IN', NULL),
    (22, 36, 'OUT', NULL),
    (23, 35, 'IN', '4th trip completed'),
    (24, 35, 'IN', NULL)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

For learning purposes, here is a self explanatory & detailed version http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d8bf4/1/0

The solution is based on calculating the 'running' count of trips from '35 to 38' and '38 to 35'. Solution is very specific to the OP query but can be optimized with a much shorter version...

```
with trip_38_to_35 as (
       select * from zonecount 
       where (zoneid=38 and status='OUT') OR (zoneid=35 and status='IN') 
       order by id asc
)
, count_start_on_38 as (    
       select count(*) as start_on_38            
       from  trip_38_to_35
       where (zoneid=38 and status='OUT') AND 
           id < 
           (    select max(id) 
                from trip_38_to_35 
                where (zoneid=35 and status='IN')
           ) /*do not count unfinished trips*/ 
) 
, count_end_on_35 as (  
       select count(*) as end_on_35
       from trip_38_to_35
       where (zoneid=35 and status='IN') 
) /*the other way of trip*/
, trip_35_to_38 as (
       select * from zonecount 
       where (zoneid=35 and status='OUT') OR (zoneid=38 and status='IN') 
       order by id asc
)
,count_start_on_35 as ( 
       select count(*) as start_on_35
       from  trip_35_to_38
       where (zoneid=35 and status='OUT') AND 
             id < 
             (    select max(id) 
                  from trip_35_to_38 
                  where (zoneid=38 and status='IN')
             ) /*do not count unfinished trips*/ 
) 
,count_end_on_38 as (   
       select count(*) as end_on_38
       from trip_35_to_38
       where (zoneid=38 and status='IN') 
)

/*sum the MIN of the two trips count*/

select 
    (case when end_on_35 > start_on_38 then start_on_38 else end_on_35 end) + 
    (case when end_on_38 > start_on_35 then start_on_35 else end_on_38 end)
from 
    count_start_on_38,
    count_end_on_35, 
    count_start_on_35,
    count_end_on_38
```

btw, 6 trips are calculated as per definition